# How to safely read the property file in Java?

Tags: java, file, properties-file

I have a property file which is like this -

```
emailFrom=hello@abc.com
emailTo=world@abc.com

# can be separated by comma
whichServer=UserServer,GuestServer

maxTestInSec=120
numberOfUsers=1000
```

Now I am reading this property file like this in Java which works if everything is set properly -

```
private static final Properties prop = new Properties();

private static String emailFrom;
private static String emailTo;
private static List<String> whichServer;
private static String maxTestInSec;
private static String numberOfUsers;

public static void main(String[] args) {
    readConfig(args);
}   

private void readConfig(String[] args) throws FileNotFoundException, IOException {
    if (!TestUtils.isEmpty(args) && args.length != 0) {
        prop.load(new FileInputStream(args[0]));
    } else {
        prop.load(TestTask.class.getClassLoader().getResourceAsStream("config.properties"));
    }

    emailFrom = prop.getProperty("emailFrom").trim();
    emailTo = prop.getProperty("emailTo").trim();
    whichServer = Arrays.asList(prop.getProperty("whichServer").trim().split(","));
    maxTestInSec = prop.getProperty("maxTestInSec").trim();
    numberOfUsers = prop.getProperty("numberOfUsers").trim();
}
```

**Problem Statement:-**

I need to make sure that if any of the property value is missing then I want to use default value for that and if by any chance that property is commented out, then also I want to use default value but I would log a warning message stating the property is missing or empty so using default values. I am trying to cover all the corner cases for reading the file -

- Now let's say, if I am not specifying values to any of my property in the above file, then I want to use default values for the property which I haven't provided and log as a warning stating that, no values have been provided for this property so using the default values. For example : Let's say if I haven't provided any value for `emailFrom` field, then I would like to use default value as `hello@abc.com` for that and similar thing for others. The default values for all the property will be :

> emailFrom=hello@abc.com
>
> emailTo=world@abc.com
>
> whichServer=UserServer
>
> maxTestInSec=30
>
> numberOfUsers=500

- Also, if any of the property is commented out then the above code is going to through NPE exception. How can I use default values in that scenario as well?

Should I start using Command Line parser for this? What is the best and clean way to handle these stuffs?

I don't want to have lot of if blocks to add a check and then set the default values.

Answer (score 1):

As of Java 8 the easiest thing to do is use [`getOrDefault()`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Map.html#getOrDefault-java.lang.Object-V-) which lets you specify a default value at the get-site. For example:

```
String email = properties.getOrDefault("emailFrom", "hello@abc.com");
```

This is clean and concise, but does mean you need to specify the default everywhere you access the property.

If that won't work for you (i.e. you'll be reading values from the properties object more than once) you can use the built-in support for default values -notice the [constructor](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Properties.html#Properties-java.util.Properties-) that takes a `default` `Properties` object. This lets you construct a `Properties` object containing your defaults, and then when you load the user's properties file it will fall back on the defaults if the user doesn't specify a value.

```
private static final Properties DEFAULTS = new Properties();
static {
  DEFAULTS.setProperty("emailFrom", "hello@abc.com");
}

public Properties getProperties() {
  Properties props = new Properties(DEFAULTS);
  props.load(...);
  return props;
}
```

Just notice that this isn't identical to how `Map`'s constructor works - the defaults are left as a separate map, and only `.getProperty()` also queries the defaults; the methods defined in `Map` like `.get()` don't. One of the many reasons it was a terrible decision for `Properties` to extend `Hashtable`, but c'est la vie...

---

These options work, but they're both error-prone since a) `Properties` is mutable and b) only some of its public methods fall back the `default` instance. I prefer to never expose `Properties` objects directly, and instead create a wrapper class with type-safe methods that expose the values my application will care about. This is a little more typing, but it's much safer to work with. It would look something like this:

```
public class ApplicationSettings {
  private final Properties properties = new Properties();
  public ApplicationSettings() {
    properties.load(...);
  }

  public String emailFrom() {
    // simple methods are concise, and encode the default right inline
    return properties.getOrDefault("emailFrom", "hello@abc.com");
  }

  public int getMaxTestSeconds() {
    // You can do more complex validation if you want, too
    String value = properties.get("maxTestInSec");
    if (value == null) {
      return 30;
    }
    int maxTestSeconds = Integer.parseInt(value);
    if (maxTestSeconds <= 0) {
      // could instead log a warning and return the default if you want
      throw new IllegalStateException(
          "maxTestInSec must be positive - was " + maxTestSeconds);
    }
    return maxTestSeconds;
  }
}
```

If you need you can also expose setters that similarly validate the values before adding them to the `Properties` object, though by default making everything read-only is generally a good practice.

Answer (score 0):

In case of a property is commented out, the return will be null, so simply do a null check.

```
if (prop.getProperty("name")==null)
```

In case of a value is not filled, check whether its equal to empty space after trim operation.

```
if (prop.getProperty("name").trim().equals(""))
```

Comment: Thanks for suggestion. With this approach if I have 20 properties in my config file, then that means I need to have 40 if blocks? Is there any other clean way of doing this?

Comment: you can get all the properties names using an enumeration like below.

Enumeration en = prop.propertyNames();

        while (en.hasMoreElements())
        {
            System.out.println(en.nextElement());
        }
and make sure all your properties are present.

Answer (score 0):

You can try cashing the properties into static map and process on that map before its being used actually.

```
private Map<String, String> rawProps = new HashMap<String, String>;
public static Map<String, String> actualProps = new HashMap<String, String>;

static {
    checkMapForNullAndReport();
}

private static void checkMapForNullAndReport() {
    // Null logic and Reporting logic
    // Empty rawProps and populate the actualProps
}
```

Something like this would work for you i believe.